# QUICKLY exporting a dynamo DB table to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

So I want to dump an entire DynamoDB table to S3.  This [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html) gives a good explanation of how to do so.  Gave it a test, it worked...great

However now I want to use it on my production data which is sizeable (>100GB).  And I want it to run quickly.  Obviously the read throughput on my DynamoDB table is a factor here, but is there a way to make sure the data pipeline is doing everything it can.  I'm not super familiar with these, the architect view after the setup has areas for instance types and instance count, but will increasing these decrease my pipeline time?  The tutorial doesn't mention anything about speed except for specifying the throughput of the table you meant to use.  Will it scale automatically based upon that?

Answer (score 0):

The template is based on the open source samples that the datapipeline team has on gihub.

The template you are referring to is [here](https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/dynamo-db-export/DynamoDB-export.json) .

If you take a look at the pipeline definition, you will find that the export is being done via a map-reduce job. The scalability of the export job should be handled by that.

If you need to get a few more details on how EMR works with DynamoDB, you will find it at the [here](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/28549). If you increase the number of instances you would need to adjust the throughput of your table accordingly to increase the parallelism of the export.